# Powershell conditionals

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to write this in powershell but can not seem to get it to work no matter how I try it.  I've used "try and catch" but it doesn't seem to work the way I want.

```
Try
   {
        write-host Attempting Reset
        CD C:\MKC1_ECU_Reuse
        ./power_on.bat
        CD C:\UTIL\XDL\XMIT\BIN
        .\xpc32_nodriver conm2.xpc -con
        .\xpc32_nodriver $global:path\$global:customer\$global:customer_reset.xpc
    }
Catch
    {
         Write-warning "Something went wrong!: $_"
         return # script failed
    }
```

In Batch, it would look like this:

```
Do some task || goto :error
goto :finished
```

Powershell will try to do the task and then go to the next line regardless of if the task completed successfully.  The task I am trying to do is to connect to an EEPROM and write to it.  If the write fails, I do not want to continue my script.  I would rather be able to display an error telling the operator that there was an issue.  I am working with what my company allows me to work with or I would use the newest Powershell that allows for || and &&.  Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the batch file you may need something like:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( 
   exit %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

That should relay the elevated exit code back to PowerShell in the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable.  Then you may be able to use the logic from the previous answer.

I guess they are forcing you to use .bat, but it might be better is you launched the underlying program from inside PowerShell.

Comment: I actually am  using Powershell to launch the program.  The issue is that I can't read the error level from the program I'm launching back to Powershell to use in an IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch only works with teminating powershell command errors.  You can test

`if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)` or `if (-not $?)` for an error.

Taking a guess at an answer:

```
$result = .\xpc32_nodriver $global:path\$global:customer\$global:customer_reset.xpc
if ($result -like '*error*') { 
   write-warning 'Something went wrong!'
   exit 1
}
```

Comment: I've tried using that as well.  It always returns 0 or True regardless of if the program xpc32_nodriver successfully connects or not.  Also, I did not mention that xpc32_nodriver was a program that I am using to connect to an EEPROM.  Not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: I guess you would have to test the output of that command then.